# how to use Python-meep?

Tags: python, meep

I am new with Python. I am using XP, I downloaded Python 2.7.2 and Python_meep 1.4.2 and I am trying to use it.  (I put both of    them in the same direction)

If I try to use some samples of Python-meep for example use_averaging i got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\Python\samples\use_averaging.py", line 7, in <module>
  from meep import *
 File "D:\Python\lib\meep.py",  line 25, in <module>
  _meep = swig_import_helper()
 File  "D:\Python\lib\meep.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
  import _meep
 ImportError: No module named _meep
```

and when i try to import meep in the Shell by typing `import  meep` I got this errror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
  import meep
 File "D:\Python\lib\meep.py", line 25, in  <module>
  _meep =  swig_import_helper()
 File "D:\Python\lib\meep.py", line 17,  in swig_import_helper
   import _meep
 ImportError: No module named _meep
```

can some body tell  me how to use this meep with Python?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this python library is a wrapper around libmeep. This is not available directly on Windows. The authors of the library say that it should be possible to build and install it  on Windows using something like cygwin - http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep_Installation

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) might work as well.